# Share connection with login and password

Tags: windows, share

I want to connect to another computer by ip with share c$ like this:

`\\ip\c$`

Can I add login and password into same line immediatelly, and how can I do it?

Comment: map it? `net use Z: \\ip\c$ /user:username password`

Comment: @AlexK. Yes. It should work. Thanks.